# PHP - Redirect REQUEST_URI - Proper Way?

Tags: php, redirect, web

I created a site (pure hobby).  What I'm basically doing is calling all ajax in background using jquery.  Yes, it's safe from SQL Injection, so no harm done, however I do not wish for user to check into firebug/developer tool and try to use the URI and manually input it in the URL toolbar and get result.  How would I go preventing that?

Example, user input into the URL box:
www.something.com/datapull.php?get=Data&Person=Sean

I have something like:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/datapull.php') !== false) { header('Location: /'); }
```

but when I do, my web get caught in a infinite loop.  I basically want the web to be at, all times: www.something.com

How do I go about keep it at THAT address without manual inputted by users?

Comment: I think you should use absolute path instead of relative

Comment: care to explain a bit more?

Comment: something like `header('Location: http://www.something.com')`

Comment: You could check for the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` being set (and matching your address) in your ajax results page. If it isn't set it means they have directly access the page by typing the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment you could try this..

In the ajax request file you can check for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` being set, and containing your own domain name..

Here's a quick example..

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Ajax Test</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ajax_receiver">

        </div>
        <script>

            $('.ajax_receiver').load('data.php');

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

data.php

```
<?php

    print_r($_SERVER);
```

If you run this as is you'll see the contents of `$_SERVER` and should see the HTTP_REFERER.

All we need to do now is add a condition to the ajax request page, in this case data.php, to exit if this isn't set, or if it isn't a request from our domain.

data.php (updated)

```
<?php
    if ( ! isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) === false)
    {
        exit;
        // or take whatever exit action you want here
    }
    print_r($_SERVER);
```

Hopefully you can use this to get you started.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed.  Couldn't think where/how I could do this.  Will get back to ya once I've successfully implement this or failed LOL.. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm basically doing is calling all ajax in background using
>   jquery. Yes, it's safe from SQL Injection, so no harm done

Sorry if I say it does not help preventing SQL Injection.

> However I do not wish for user to check into firebug/developer tool and
>   try to use the URI and manually input it in the URL toolbar and get
>   result.

If a link is inaccessible by a web browser, so is your AJAX.